# React Class Component - adding a simple function

Tags: reactjs, methods

I'm just starting out with React and have working code that is validating some input fields in real time. I have some common code around the validation logic and wanted to extract that to a method to handle common things but I must be doing something wrong cause I can't introduce a simple method to do anything. below is a truncated flavor of the Component I'm working with. The new method I'm introducing is called 'test' and I was expecting it to just log something to the console for each keystroke as I type in the inputs.

```
class AReactComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);

    this.state = {
        ...
    };
  }

  // simple method
  test() {
    console.log('test');
  }

  handleInput(event) {

      // blows up
      test();
      ...
  }
}
```

**Here's the error from my dev console**

[image]

Is there a 'correct' way to introduce simple methods that don't deal with event listening and such? Let me know if more info is needed and apologies if any of my syntax isn't correct.

Comment: try using replacing with arrow functions

Comment: What does the render function look like?

Comment: Try replacing ```test()``` with ```this.test()``` inside the handle input method. In your case test could be calling the jest test function instead of the class test method.

Comment: This is a general JS issue, not a React. If you are in a Class instance and want to call other methods of this instance - you need `this.` in front. So just use `this.test()`

Comment: adding this. did fix the problem, much appreciated!